# Converting arrays to std_logic_vector in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I have declared an array

```
type REG_TYPE is array(0 to FIR_ORDER - 1) of
  signed(DATA_WIDTH + COEFF_WIDTH - 1 downto 0)
```

and a signal `temp` of this type:

```
signal temp: REG_TYPE;
```

To meet the objective, I need to use adders and multipliers. On applying certain logic, I'm facing a situation where I need to call an adder whose result is a `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR` to be mapped to temp of type `REG_TYPE`.

This leads to an error. How to proceed?

Comment: Your reg type is an array of signed words. A slv is a single word. You need to determine how the slv is split up to map to your array. Probably with a custom conversion function.

Comment: Added two `signed` values results again in a `signed` value. There is no `std_logic_vector` result. If you have so, please add the code to your answer. Currently you are not providing enough code to verify your problem.

Comment: Well, its a requirement to replace the + and * in the code with adders and multipliers. [for eg :next_reg(i) <= reg(i+1)+(signed(data_in_reg))*coeff_array(i+1)];  Here reg is an array, data_in_reg is a vector and coeff array is again an array type. To achieve the objective i have assigned [vtemp as (signed(data_in_reg))*coeff_array(i+1)]] by declaring vtemp as a signed vector. Now finally it would be adding reg(i+1) with vtemp. Since the adder function i have used the result to be a std_logic_vector, i am getting the error and unable to proceed. Please help me

Comment: Your comment makes little sense, as + and * will work just fine in VHDL and will be infered correctly in the hardware. So replacing + and * functions with entities does little more than bloat your code. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Its an assignment to be done

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for you to be helped, you need to edit your question to add (a) the code (as a [MCVE]) and (b) the error message.